# Using Spring cloud config server in AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, spring-cloud-config

I have created a lambda which is responsible for creating a springboot application using aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2 dependecy. this lambda is triggered by SQS event.I am parsing inputsteam for the input sqs event to get the required details. It is then converted to api call so SQS messages will then handled by spring controller to perfrom business logic.
We already have cloud config server created for common configuration and I am trying to use the same within my lambda application. To make use of cloud config 2 changes are done

1. Include cloud-starter-config depdency in pom
2. specicy app name,cloud url with region in bootstrap yml

when I deploy this lambda , the depencies are not resolved , meaning the property values from config server are not read in springboot application.
Could not find much details about cloud config and lambda support. what am I missing?

Comment: Is there any error you are getting? I think that you forgot `spring.cloud.config.label` property. Will not work without it.

Comment: @Pallavi296 Hi, I am also looking to deploy cloud config on aws lambda. Could you point me to some documentation you may have referred?